Test of linear constraints in RS codes - has the Ligero approach a typo in both papers?
In both Ligero papers 2017 and 2022, in the description on how to test linear constraints in interleaved linear codes (given below), I find the following inconsistency (it's most probably me to blame), which is not present in ligero++ simply because a factor is selected =0 which removes it.
I would be grateful for someone pointing out where my misconception is, if any.
Below follows the protocol from 2.
We have the definition of $r_{ic}$ as related to $r^TA$. (1). This definition is then accordingly used in 3. and the left hand side of the check in 5.(a) - (2).
This is also in accordance with the equation following a few lines below the protocol (4).
Crucial Point to be clarified:
the right hand side should imho read as related to $r^Tb$, but in fact is related to $(r^TA)b$, because it applies $r_{ic}$.
As far as I understood linear codes and constraints, from $Ax=b$ follows that, for u encoding x follows $Au=b$ and hence $(r^TA)u=r^Tb$, which would also imply that there is a mistake in the right-hand side of 5.(a).
The third paper ligero++ uses $b=0$, therefore the problem resolves.

A few lines below the protocol:


I think that you are correct. If we write $r^T=(\rho_{11},\ldots,\rho_{1,\ell},\ldots,\rho_{m,1},\ldots,\rho_{m,\ell})$ then the RHS of 5(a) should be $\sum\rho_{i,c}b_{i,c}$. It looks like the authors have tripped themselves up by using $r_{ic}$ to represent the entries of both $r^TA$ and $r^T$. It's probably worth dropping them a line to be sure.

Same conclusion on my side after another day of examination. I add my 'corrected and commented' protocol below.

I mentioned the question to one of the authors; it's probably best if we let them confirm that it's a typo.

This is Muthu (one of the authors of Ligero). Indeed this a typo. Thanks for catching it Alex. The RHS must be $r^Tb$ and we indeed got tripped up by using $r_{ic}$ for $r^TA$. We will update the eprint asap.

Based on further analysis, as also pointed out by Daniel S, I conclude that it's actually an error.
TLTR:
The prover calculates $\bar{r}=encoded (r^TA)$, which goes into $q$ (actually an encoded value), while the right hand side of 5(a) need to use the encoded $r$ and encoded $b$.
In addition, the equation (4) given above should use $\hat{=}$, as it is only an equivalency, not a strict equal. The reason is that the left side is encoded, while the right side is not.
See my commented version of the protocol below for details.

